# castle windsor ITypedFactoryComponentSelectors constructor parameter by type not name

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, factory

I am using an external library where I do not have control of naming conventions for object constructors. There are various constructors which differentiate by parameter type. Thus I want to override the convention in the typed factory to retrieve by exact name of the parameter and use the type.

e.g.

```
GenderTemplateViewModel CreateGenderTemplateViewModel();
GenderTemplateViewModel CreateGenderTemplateViewModel(GenderTemplateModel     genderTemplateModel); 
GenderTemplateViewModel CreateGenderTemplateViewModel(GenderTemplateModel     genderTemplateModel, string extraInfo);
```

Thus can I grab the right constructor by the types, not names of the parameters?
i.e. which method to override and how

```
public class ParameterbyTypeNotNameTypedFactoryComponentSelector :    DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
{
    protected override Type GetComponentType(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {

        return base.GetComponentType(method, arguments);
    }
    protected override string GetComponentName(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {

        return base.GetComponentName(method, arguments);
    }
    protected override IDictionary GetArguments(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {

        return base.GetArguments(method, arguments);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the GetArguments() method. The following should work:

```
public class ExtendedTypedFactoryComponentSelector : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
{
    protected override IDictionary GetArguments(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {
        if (arguments == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        ParameterInfo[] parameters = method.GetParameters();
        Arguments arg = new Arguments(new IArgumentsComparer[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arg.Contains(parameters[i].ParameterType))
            {
                if (this.isFunc(method.DeclaringType))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Factory delegate {0} has duplicated arguments of type {1}. Using generic purpose delegates with duplicated argument types is unsupported, because then it is not possible to match arguments properly. Use some custom delegate with meaningful argument names or interface based factory instead.", method.DeclaringType, parameters[i].ParameterType));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                arg.Add(parameters[i].ParameterType, arguments[i]);
            }
            arg.Add(parameters[i].Name, arguments[i]);
        }
        return arg;
    }

    private bool isFunc(Type type)
    {
        return ((type.FullName != null) && type.FullName.StartsWith("System.Func"));
    }
}
```

Note: This is just a slightly different version of the original implementation of `DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick quite nicely. I realized it would be a relatively minor change, but was a matter of knowing which method to override. Thanks again.

Comment: Note: Currently all constructors have one parameter, the factory injects the rest, so have not had the exception thrown, and have not tested that section.